# Flag provided but not defined -d while running docker container

Tags: docker

I am trying to setup this https://github.com/jwasham/computer-science-flash-cards on my local pc using docker but after I have built my image,when I try

```
docker run -d -p 8000:8000 --name cs-flash-cards cs-flash-cards
```

it says

```
flag provided but not defined: -d
```

Any ideas how to fix this and run this container?

EDIT(on docker info;docker version I get the following info):

```
Containers: 0
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 10
Server Version: 1.12.5
Storage Driver: devicemapper
 Pool Name: docker-202:1-312980-pool
 Pool Blocksize: 65.54 kB
 Base Device Size: 10.74 GB
 Backing Filesystem: xfs
 Data file: /dev/loop0
 Metadata file: /dev/loop1
 Data Space Used: 877.5 MB
 Data Space Total: 107.4 GB
 Data Space Available: 2.019 GB
 Metadata Space Used: 1.913 MB
 Metadata Space Total: 2.147 GB
 Metadata Space Available: 2.019 GB
 Thin Pool Minimum Free Space: 10.74 GB
 Udev Sync Supported: true
 Deferred Removal Enabled: false
 Deferred Deletion Enabled: false
 Deferred Deleted Device Count: 0
 Data loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data
 WARNING: Usage of loopback devices is strongly discouraged for production use. Use `--storage-opt dm.thinpooldev` to specify a custom block storage device.
 Metadata loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata
 Library Version: 1.02.110 (2015-10-30)
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: null host bridge overlay
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Security Options: apparmor seccomp
Kernel Version: 4.4.0-45-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 990.7 MiB
Name: ip-172-31-33-253
ID: QPUK:E7BB:Y2PW:MPJR:L2X4:4AMT:VHAT:SOXK:3A2N:UKI2:ZXRK:QF4S
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING: No swap limit support
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Client:
 Version:      1.12.5
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.4
 Git commit:   7392c3b
 Built:        Fri Dec 16 02:42:17 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.12.5
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.4
 Git commit:   7392c3b
 Built:        Fri Dec 16 02:42:17 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Comment: post `docker info ; docker version` and the OS of the host, maybe related https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/20081

Comment: thank you for responding. I have edited my description with the required data

Comment: Ok, so I went to that link and I replaced -d with daemon and it solved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the next person who has the same problem.

this was for SystemD on Ubuntu LTS and the docker.service file
was the fix.

If you are on Centos7, you may have an extra file called override.conf
this is used to override the docker.service in systemd.
This file also has the -d flag
and is located in 
/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/override.conf

replace -d with deamon here 
do systemctl daemon-reload and docker will start up.